# The receiving part of the SPI in STM32F0 is not working

Tags: stm32, spi

The MCU I used is STM32F042K6T6. I have configured the SPI in bidirectional mode in order to read the sensor MLX90316. Now the read function is blocked in waiting the the RXNE signal. If I have understood correctly, once I have put the SPI into rx mode, the SCLK is automatically generated and the receiving procedure is started. But the RXNE is never set and nothing in RxFIFO. It seems that the receiving part of the SPI is not working at all. Even I put the MCU in full duplex mode, when I initial the data transmitting by writing the SPI1->DR, the data is transmitted successfully but the problem still remains.

The same code is tested on a STM32F405RGT6 and it functions correctly(if I don't care about the data because the GPIO is not configured). I totally have no idea about this strange problem...

Thank you in advance.:)

The Initial function

```
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_SPI1, ENABLE);
/* SPI configuration -------------------------------------------------------*/
SPI_I2S_DeInit(SPI1);
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_Direction = SPI_Direction_1Line_Tx; // Initially Tx
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_Mode = SPI_Mode_Master;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_DataSize = SPI_DataSize_8b;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CPOL = SPI_CPOL_Low; // Clock steady high
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CPHA = SPI_CPHA_2Edge; // Data write on rising (second) edge
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_NSS = SPI_NSS_Soft;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BaudRatePrescaler_4;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_FirstBit = SPI_FirstBit_LSB;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CRCPolynomial = 7;
SPI_Init(SPI1, &SPI_InitStructure);
SPI_RxFIFOThresholdConfig(SPI1, SPI_RxFIFOThreshold_QF);
SPI_Cmd(SPI1, ENABLE);
```

The tramsmission function is:

```
void spi_send_8bit(uint8_t Data){
while (SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1, SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE) == RESET); //wait buffer empty
SPI_SendData8(SPI1, Data);
while (SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1, SPI_I2S_FLAG_BSY) == SET); //wait finish sending}

uint8_t spi_recv_8bit(void){
while (SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1, SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE) == RESET) ; // wait data receive
return SPI_ReceiveData8(SPI1);}



static void Read(void){

MLX90316_1_Set(); //Pull down the CS line
SPI_BiDirectionalLineConfig(SPI1, SPI_Direction_Tx);
spi_send_8bit(0xAA);
spi_send_8bit(0xFF);


while (SPI_GetReceptionFIFOStatus(SPI1) != SPI_ReceptionFIFOStatus_Empty)
    SPI_ReceiveData8(SPI1);

SPI_Cmd(SPI1, DISABLE);
SPI_BiDirectionalLineConfig(SPI1, SPI_Direction_Rx);
SPI_Cmd(SPI1, ENABLE);

Data[0] = spi_recv_8bit();
Data[1] = spi_recv_8bit();
Data[2] = spi_recv_8bit();
Data[3] = spi_recv_8bit();
SPI_BiDirectionalLineConfig(SPI1, SPI_Direction_Tx);
spi_send_8bit(0xFF);
spi_send_8bit(0xFF);
spi_send_8bit(0xFF);
spi_send_8bit(0xFF);
MLX90316_1_Cl();}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I solved it by setting up FRXTH bit in SPI1->CR2 register.

Answer (score 1):

This function won't work:

> `uint8_t spi_recv_8bit(void){
>   while (SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1, SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE) == RESET) ; // wait datareceive
>   return SPI_ReceiveData8(SPI1);}`

You *have* to write a dummy value to `DR` register to trigger the `CLK` pulses in SPI master mode. You could use your `spi_send_8bit()` function to do that.

Comment: in fact I have tried this and found that if I write 4 bytes data into the Tx FIFO  and record the SR register, I found that when the amount of the Tx FIFO decrease, which means the device is sending the data properly, the amount of the Rx FIFO never increase and thus the RXNE bit is never set. I have tried the same code in 2 diffierent STM32F0 to eleminate the possibility of a damaged chip. I think maybe I have missed something...

Answer (score 1):

While this may be an "old" post now I found it so it may be of use to others, I also have a problem with RXNE on both an STM32F030 and 042.

I found single stepping (IAR IDE) that the CPU hangs at the RXNE poll loop:

```
while (SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1, SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE) == RESET);
```

I tried:

```
while (SPI_GetReceptionFIFOStatus(SYS_SPI) == SPI_ReceptionFIFOStatus_Empty);
```

Same result, the receiver doesn't let us know it's completed.

I put a breakpoint on the line following these, which logically would not have been reached- it is!!! Is this a SPI peripheral or debug issue perhaps.
RXNE's descriotion leaves a lot to be desired, it almost reads as it it's "FIFO ALMOST FULL"

Comment: So finally I found out what had happened. It is related to the RCC. There are two RC oscillator available in STM32F0, one is 8Mhz and the other one is 48Mhz. If I choose the 8Mz RC oscillator and use  PLL to have a 48Mhz clock, this problem occurs. But If I use 48Mhz oscillator directly as the master clock, the SPI would works normally.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem related, the clock out is never sent, even after the instruction  `SPI2->CR1 &= ~SPI_CR1_BIDIOE;`

My solution: Before the above instruction, put:

```
SPI2->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_RXONLY;
SPI2->CR1 &= ~SPI_CR1_RXONLY;
```

This outputs the clock and sets the bit `SPI_FLAG_RXNE`.
I already use the internal 48MHz clock.